# Pass parameters to Datatable

Tags: ajax, datatable

I want to pass parameters from ajax datatable to filter info, I've got the following:

[image]

I want to pass select "nombremedico" and two inputs: initial_date and final_date to fetch_pasar.php (for filtering info in datatable):

```
 <div class="col-sm-4"><label> <span>Medico</span> </label>
                <select id="nombremedico" name="nombremedico"  class="form-control" onchange="showname(this)" required>
                    <option selected disabled value=""> - Seleccione Medico - </option>
                    <?php include("config/fetchmedico.php") ?>
                </select>
            </div>  
          
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label> <span>Fecha Inicio</span> </label>
              <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="initial_date" id="initial_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" style="height: 40px;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label> <span>Fecha Fin</span> </label>
              <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="final_date" id="final_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" style="height: 40px;"/>
            </div>
```

This is my datatable ajax  code:

```
   var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
       "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
       dom: 'Blfrtip',
      buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
          ],
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "Todos"] ],
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetch_pasar.php",
     type:"POST"
    },
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
    $('#total_order').html(settings.json.total);
    $('#total_pago').html(settings.json.total_pago);
    }
   });
```

Please anyideas?, I dont how to pass parameters from ajax datatable to file fetch_pasar.php

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in the ajax object to set any extra parameters to send in the request

```
"ajax" : {
    url:"fetch_pasar.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: function ( d ) {
        d.nombremedico = $('#nombremedico').val();
        d.initial_date = $('#initial_date').val();
        d.final_date = $('#final_date').val();
    }
},
```